# How to pass in a datagrid selection to use in ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've got data templates in Window.Resources

```
    <TemplateSelectors:Schedule x:Key="templateSelector">
        <TemplateSelectors:Schedule.DailyTemplate>
            <DataTemplate> (stuff here)  </DataTemplate>
        </TemplateSelectors:Schedule.DailyTemplate>
```

I'm using them in a datagrid

```
<DataGrid RowDetailsTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}"...
```

Ok all well and good, but now I want to display the data template someone else on the window. So I try this:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
```

But I get this

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The method

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object jobOb, DependencyObject container)
{
```

Is expecting object jobOb but it is null (as expected). How can I pass in the datagrid selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler than I thought. Just need to set the content to the selected item on the datagrid.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=datagrid, Path=SelectedItem}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
```